# How to do a paged QueryDSL query with Spring JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

QueryDSL defines an `OrderSpecifier` interface and an instance for that can be easily obtained for any field by calling `asc()` or `desc()`. The `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` interface of Spring Data JPA even has a `findAll()` method which takes `OrderSpecifier`s as parameters.

`org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest` however doesn't know anything about QueryDSL and it has its own way for defining query sort order, namely `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort`. It can contain a number of `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Order`s which are a lot like `OrderSpecifier`s, except that they are not type safe etc.

So, if I want to make paged query which uses sorting, is there really no way of using QueryDSL for defining that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work like this if you can't find another way

```
private Sort sortBy(Path<?> path) {
    return new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, path.getMetadata().getExpression().toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. A bit ugly, but much less so than using hard-coded expression names. Could you please add the missing parenthesis so that others can copy-paste you comment without modifying it.

Comment: `getExpression()` seems to have been removed and there seems to be no simple way of getting the whole expression name, only the last element's with `getName()`.

Comment: The whole expression serialized is `path.toString()`, but it contains also the name of the root variable

Answer (score 9):

I know it's been a while and I'm not sure this was available at the time of the OP but there is now a [QPageRequest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/QPageRequest.html) object introduced which allows for sorting via QueryDSL to be added to spring data jpa Query DSL...

Answer (score 8):

Here is a much simpler way to construct a `Sort` object using QueryDSL:

```
new QSort(user.manager.firstname.asc())
```

Then you can use it in a `PageRequest` like so:

```
new PageRequest(0, 10, new QSort(user.manager.firstname.asc()))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getExpression()` method has been removed, and I had expressions akin to `QPost.post.period.periCode` which *needed* a traversal, and without the complete name of expression I couldn't do anything about it, so now I made a method that gathers `period.periCode` and works perfectly on `QPost.post`.

```
private String resolveOrderPath(Path<?> path) {
    StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder(path.getMetadata().getName());
    path = path.getMetadata().getParent();
    while(!path.getMetadata().isRoot()) {
        stringBuffer.insert(0, path.getMetadata().getName() + ".");
        path = path.getMetadata().getParent();
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}

Path<?> path = QPost.post.period.periCode;
String propertyPath = resolveOrderPath(path);
Sort sort = new Sort("asc".equals(sSortDir0) ? Sort.Direction.ASC : Sort.Direction.DESC, propertyPath);
```