# How can I convert a spring data Sort to a querydsl OrderSpecifier?

Tags: spring-data, querydsl

This is basically the opposite of this:
[How to do a paged QueryDSL query with Spring JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673213/how-to-do-a-paged-querydsl-query-with-spring-jpa)

This is for a custom query for which i can't use any of the findAll() methods.

EDIT:

Posted the wrong link. Now corrected.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do somethings like this: But make sure to trim the o.getProperty() so you only pass the property and not "alias."+property

```
if (pageable != null) {
    query.offset(pageable.getOffset());
    query.limit(pageable.getPageSize());
    for (Sort.Order o : pageable.getSort()) {
        PathBuilder<Object> orderByExpression = new PathBuilder<Object>(Object.class, "object");

        query.orderBy(new OrderSpecifier(o.isAscending() ? com.mysema.query.types.Order.ASC
                : com.mysema.query.types.Order.DESC, orderByExpression.get(o.getProperty())));
    }
}
```

Comment: marked as answer as my question was answered and I came to the same solution except using MyClass.class instead of Object.class. However how do i do this in a generic way, eg MyClass is actually <T extends MyClass>?

Comment: You should reuse the orderByExpression, since it is a common parent for the order by children. Also the name is misleading, since the children are the actual "order by expressions".

Comment: This kind of works for my case, but not completely. The problem is that I need to sort calculated fields (sum, count). I have them as aliases but the problem is the PathBuilder always appends to the query "alias." + property. In the example it always returns "ORDER BY object.{alias}" which is invalid. How can I get QueryDSL to just append "ORDER BY {alias}" ?

Comment: This worked for me after some fiddling. Anyone know if it's secure?

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if it is still relevant but there is an implementation in the spring data jpa for doing the conversion between a data.domain.Sort (Spring JPA) Object to an OrderSpecifier (QueryDSL).

[GIT Source of Querydsl Support in Spring JPA](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/Querydsl.java)

It is really ugly implementation but you could still reuse it for your own purpose as the method is private:

```
public JPQLQuery applySorting(Sort sort, JPQLQuery query)
```

But if you use Spring data JPA, in your custom Repository implementation, you just need to do:

```
public Page<MyObject> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {

    QMyObject myObject = QMyObject.myObject;
    JPQLQuery jPQLQuery = from(myObject)
            .join(myObject.user)
            .where(predicate);
    jPQLQuery = getQuerydsl().applyPagination(pageable, jPQLQuery);
    List<MyObject> myObjectList = jPQLQuery.list(myObject);
    long count =  jPQLQuery.count();
    Page<MyObject> myObjectPage = new PageImpl<MyObject>(myObjectList, pageable, count);
    return myObjectPage;  
}
```

Hope it could help!

Answer (score 5):

```
private OrderSpecifier<?>[] getSortedColumn(Sort sorts){   
    return sorts.toList().stream().map(x ->{
        Order order = x.getDirection().name() == "ASC"? Order.ASC : Order.DESC;
        SimplePath<Object> filedPath = Expressions.path(Object.class, Qobject, x.getProperty());
        return new OrderSpecifier(order, filedPath);
    }).toArray(OrderSpecifier[]::new);
}
```

then you can use like this:

```
  .where(...), 
  .orderBy(getSortedColumn(pageable.getSort()))
```

Comment: What is `objectDTO`?

Comment: It means new Instance generated by Querydsl.

Answer (score 4):

`org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Order` and `com.querydsl.core.types.Order` and are so similar, yet there is no straightforward conversion between the two. This is somewhat improved version of [frozenfury](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13097615/432777) answer:

```
PathBuilder<Entity> entityPath = new PathBuilder<>(Entity.class, "entity");
for (Order order : pageable.getSort()) {
    PathBuilder<Object> path = entityPath.get(order.getProperty());
    query.orderBy(new OrderSpecifier(com.querydsl.core.types.Order.valueOf(order.getDirection().name()), path));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to directly apply the sort into your base query without having to convert to OrderSpecifier<?>, you can leverage `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.Querydsl`.

```
JPQLQuery<?> query = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager);
//prepare your base query
query.select(<YourQEntity>).from(<YourQEntity>).where(<whereClause>);

Querydsl querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, (new PathBuilderFactory()).create(<YourEntityClass>.class));

//apply org.springframework.data.domain.Sort
querydsl.applySorting(pageable.getSort(), query);
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Comment: Best answear! It just works (may 2023)